# Time counter with JavaScript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, count, timer, counter

I want to implement a time counter with JavaScript or PHP. I did some looking on Google and tried it, but didn't get the output I need.

Users will enter the time in the textbox provided, then I need to give them a counter from the time they entered.

Example: If I enter `1:27:38` and click on submit, the time should decrease and I should get an alert when it reaches 0.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- //
var timeleft;
var nextdue;
var tick = 1000;



function parseTime(t) {
 var tt = ("0:00:"+t);
 tt = tt.split(":").reverse();
 return (tt[0] * 1000)+(tt[1] * 60000)+(tt[2] * 3600000);
}



function zeroPad(n) {
 if (n<10) return "0"+n;
 return ""+n;
}



function makeTime(t) {
 if (t<0) return "0:00:00";
 var tt=t+999;
 return Math.floor(tt/3600000)+":"+
 zeroPad(Math.floor(tt/60000)%60)+":"+
 zeroPad(Math.floor(tt/1000)%60);
}



function startTimer() {
 nextdue = new Date().getTime();
 timeleft = parseTime(document.timerform.timerbox.value);
 runTimer();
}



function runTimer() {
 document.timerform.timerbox.value=makeTime(timeleft);
 if (timeleft<=0) alert ("Time's up!");
 else {
  var timecorr = (new Date().getTime())-nextdue;
  if (timecorr>0 && timecorr<3000) {
   timeleft -= (tick+timecorr);
   nextdue += tick;
   if (timeleft<1) setTimeout ("runTimer()",tick+timeleft);
   else setTimeout("runTimer()",Math.max(1,tick-timecorr));
  }
  else {
   nextdue=(new Date().getTime())+tick;
   timeleft-=tick;
   if (timeleft<1) setTimeout ("runTimer()",tick+timeleft);
   else setTimeout("runTimer()",tick);
  }
 } 
}



// -->
</script>



<form name="timerform">
  Decimal places: <input type="text" name="timerbox" value="0:00:00"></input>
  <input type="button" value="Start timer" onClick="startTimer()"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, this is what i need

Thanx Robert, this saved some time for me

Answer (score 1):

In PHP:

```
list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $_POST['time']);

$seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;

for ($i = $seconds; $i > 0; $i--)
{
   echo $i;
   sleep(1);
   flush();
}

echo 'Countdown finished.';
```